# Does Magento or Zend cache DB connection strings?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, magento, failover

I have a Magento app running on a pretty standard Apache/Zend platform.  I am pointing Magento to a new db by modifying the local.xml, however it does not seem to be honoring my changes, even after a restart of the app.

More specifically, I have db1 and db2. I am changing Magento to point to db2, however the app continues pointing to db1.  As a matter of fact, I can completely shut down db2, and even though the app is pointing to db2, it doesn't care...and continues running just fine.  If I shut down db1, the app fails, even though it's config has it pointing to db2.

I am hoping that it is just a caching setting somewhere in Magento or Zend that I am unaware of, but I find it odd that it persists after an app restart.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the entire Magento configuration tree (of which `local.xml` is a part) gets cached.  Use the UI in `System -> Cache Management` to clear the configuration cache, or manually blow away your cache storage (i.e. remove `var/cache/*')

Comment: Great answer.  This was exactly what I needed.  Clearing this cache caused the app to honor the changes I was making in the local.xml.  Just to elaborate, I just blew away the /var/cache dir on my filesystem, I did not clear the cache in Magento.